# Mapping a class instance to a number

Tags: java, go

I'm extremely new to Java and have been trying to use Nested class for the first time.
I have an outer class with 2 inner class and i'm trying to be able to have
the innerclass

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    class Person {
      class Like {
      }
      **public static Map<Integer, Like> Likes;**
    }
}
```

Is it possible in Java ?
In Golang that would look like this for example :

```
type Like struct {

}

type Person struct {
    Name  string
    **Likes map[int]Like**
}
```

I might be going the wrong way and maybe a better OOP approch of doing that exist or is it possible this way ?

Comment: Have you tried the code that you posted? What went wrong? (Was there perhaps an error message for you to Google?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and your code will be like

```
  class Client{

class Outer{
    class Phone{ 
        class Like{
              public void sayHello(){
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        }

        public static void method(Outer.Phone.Like g){
            l.sayHello();
        }
    }

}

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Client q = new Client();
    Client.Outer o = q.new Outer();
    Client.Outer.Phone p = o.new Phone();
    Client.Outer.Phone.Like l = p.new Like();        
    p.method(l);      //call sayHello and print Hello
```

}